# Geotagging/Plotting MapKit Corelocation

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-location, mapkit

I have created an app that simply shows the user's current position on a google map using the MapKit.

However I would now like to go a bit further and add a bit more functionality to the app by allowing the user to plot points on the map themselves.

I somehow believe using CoreLocation will accomplish this by receiving and saving coordinates of where the user selects on the map.

Am I right in saying this? and any ideas on how I would implement this? Links or tutorials would be helpful too, and also any personal experience/ideas in the matter would be great.

I have created an app that implements coreLocation before this app, compiled/ran perfectly.. just didnt update user location and latitude/longitude. the code is shown below for that app:

This is only in the AppDelegate.m which is what does all the work basically.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize locationManager;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 100;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

#pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.2;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.2;

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.span = span;
    region.center = newLocation.coordinate;

    [viewController.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    viewController.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

    viewController.latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    viewController.latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
}

@end
```

Comment: I don't understand what your exact question is.  By the way, in didUpdateToLocation, you are setting only viewController.latitude.text to latitude and then to longitude.

Comment: oh yeahs thank you for the little tweak there as I just copied and pasted it once I had typed it all out (havent had the change to debug as nothing happens when run it). My question is basically to get help on how to get my application to plot points on a map such as MapKit. Where would I start and what is needed? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you a signed up iOS developer? Apple's code samples include a few map apps, they should get you started.

Since you're not having any luck while searching for tutorials online here are some terms that might help

**MKAnnotation** : What you'd use to mark a location on the map (a pin, a flag, a bit of text)
**UIGestureRecognizer** : Use one of these to find out when a user has touched the map, look for touch-and-hold events as a good sign they want to mark it because touch-and-drag would be for moving the map around
**MKMapPoint** : A place on a flat map of earth as used in iOS. Remember that these are different from CLLocationCoordinate2D's longitude and latitude but you can easily convert between them.